# How to show selected user input in my HTML form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP form which saves user data to a MySQL database.

I want to show the user which information is held about them and display it in a form in order for them to update or edit the values.

I have a problem in getting the user's saved data from the database in a PHP loop and show that to user in order for them to update or edit it.

Below is the piece of code:

```
            <?php
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'phpmyadmin', 'Test@2000', 'user');

                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id='$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            ?>

            <fieldset><label>Birthday</label>
                <select name="birthday">
                <?php
                    for ($i = 1300; $i <= 1397; $i++) {
                        echo "<option >$i</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                    <fieldset>
                <button name="btn" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show into the form's Select input the birthday value that user selected originally, in order to edit or update by user.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch info about user with id (e.g:) 5? and print them using the loop ?
Please add more information such as: What  are you trying to achieve, how should it look, what's already happening.

Comment: and where's the opening form tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` children elements `<option>` does support a `selected` tag to indicate that it was the selected value, so by adding the selected tag like so `<option value='1' selected>` you can have that as the selected value.

You'll also want to probably add the `$i` value into your option element to ensure that the values are being submitted properly.

Mozilla documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: What 's OP trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like he wants to have a 'my profile' page where users can edit their birthdays. Assuming he is using similar code from when he initially registered his users, I'm showing him how to have the dropdown automatically default to the intended value.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code in this way.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'phpmyadmin', 'Test@2000', 'user');

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

        <fieldset><label>Birthday</label>
            <select name="birthday">
            <?php for ($i = 1300; $i <= 1397; $i++) {
                echo "<option" . (($i == $row['birthdayYear']) ? 'selected="true"' : '') . ">$i</option>";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
                <fieldset>
            <button name="btn" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, it returned blanked drop down!

Comment: Use this instead, (($i == $row['birthdayYear']) ? 'selected="true"' : '')

Answer (score 0):

**A.) WITH PDO MODULE**

It is best practice today to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. This is done through the PDO object.

Set for select the autocomplete="off" attribute, because Firefox apparently has a bug with the selected="selected" that needs this to be set.

See if it is the user's birthday, we can use intval to compare.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'phpmyadmin';
$password = 'Test@2000';
$db_name = 'user';

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host:=' . $host . '; dbname=' . $db_name, $username, $password);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id = :id;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
        <fieldset><label>Birthday</label>
            <select name="birthday" autocomplete="off">
            <?php for ($i = 1300; $i <= 1397; $i++) {
                if($i === intval($row['birthdayYear'])){
                  echo "<option selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                } else {
                  echo "<option>$i</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
                <fieldset>
            <button name="btn" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**B.) Please at least try option A.), but if it doesn't work:**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'phpmyadmin', 'Test@2000', 'user');

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
        <fieldset><label>Birthday</label>
            <select name="birthday" autocomplete="off">
            <?php for ($i = 1300; $i <= 1397; $i++) {
                if($i === intval($row['birthdayYear'])){
                  echo "<option selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                } else {
                  echo "<option>$i</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
                <fieldset>
            <button name="btn" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```